#  How to define attributes to optional element?

Tags: xml, parsing, dtd

My XML may contain multiple `param` entries, each with `key` and `value` attribute  likes this:

```
<entry id="entry1">
    <classParams>
       <param key="pluginid" value="monitorPlugin" />
       <param key="pluginid2" value="monitorPlugin2" />
    </classParams>
</entry>
```

AND/OR one single `classParams` only containing one string like this:

```
<entry id="entry2">
    <classParams>
      Im a string
    </classParams>
</entry>
```

My DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT classParams ( #PCDATA | param* )* >
<!ATTLIST id CDATA #REQUIRED value CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT param ( #PCDATA ) >
```

How do I define my DTD correctly, concerning the two entry types and the attribute definition for only one type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with this definition. I now only use `id` and put the value in `param`.

```
<!ELEMENT classParams ( #PCDATA  | param )* >
         <!ELEMENT param ( #PCDATA ) >
         <!ATTLIST param 
            id CDATA #REQUIRED
         >
```

Answer (score 1):

This DTD should work...

```
<!ELEMENT entry (classParams)>
<!ATTLIST entry
          id CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT classParams (#PCDATA|param)*>

<!ELEMENT param (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST param
          key CDATA #REQUIRED
          value CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does `EMPTY` define? What is the definition if I want either `key` OR `id` to be an attribute, not both at the same time allowed but one at least always required?

Comment: `EMPTY` means it's an empty element. In your case, that should be `#PCDATA`. (I'll edit.) In DTD, you can't do "OR" with attribute declarations. The best you could do is make both implied and do the check some other way.